# PHP DirectoryIterator for remote location

Tags: php, iterator

I am trying to read folder of mp3 files on remote server. Would this be possible to do with DirectoryIterator?

```
$dir = "http://pspc.dyndns.info/~pspc/audio/2018-10-28_1528/";

$dit = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
foreach ($dit as $fileinfo) {

}
```

I am getting an error:

```
 Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: DirectoryIterator::__construct(http:/pspc.dyndns.info/~pspc/audio/2018-10-28_1528/,http:/pspc.dyndns.info/~pspc/audio/2018-10-28_1528/): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (code: 123) in
```

Comment: DirectoryIterator can deal with remote URL paths as well? I don't find anything like that written [here](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php)

Comment: I believe that you can have a DirectoryIterator like behaviour in remote servers if you build your own "RemoteDirectoryIterator", connecting to the server and then getting the files into a iterator approach